# jQuery deferred ajax execution order

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, promise, deferred

I want to chain multiple functions one after another with promises, and each of the functions make an AJAX call.

something like this:

```js
function myfunction1() {
  console.log("myfunction1");
  return $.ajax({
    url: "/"
  }).always(function() {
    console.log("myfunction1 done");
  });
}

function myfunction2() {
  console.log("myfunction2");
  return $.ajax({
    url: "/"
  }).always(function() {
    console.log("myfunction2 done");
  });
}


myfunction1()
  .then(myfunction2());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I would need `myfunction1`'s callback to run before calling `myfunction2`.
So I would need this order:

```
myfunction1
myfunction1 done
myfunction2
myfunction2 done
```

but the code sample runs in this order:

```
myfunction1
myfunction2
myfunction1 done
myfunction2 done
```

Any help would be appreciated

**Solution:**

Parentheses aren't needed

```
myfunction1().then(myfunction2);
```

instead of:

```
myfunction1().then(myfunction2());
```

thanks @bergi

Comment: `.then(myfunction2());` calls the function immediately and passes the result promise to `then`. You want to pass a callback instead: `.then(myfunction2)`.

Comment: Wow, I almost missed this comment, it solved my problem, huge thanks!

Comment: @inverz - On this site, you are never supposed to edit the solution into your question - ever.  Questions are to remain questions.  If nobody else posts an answer and you find the solution, you can post an answer yourself.  Or, if someone else has posted the answer, then you can accept that answer by checking the green checkmark next to that answer.  This will indicate to the community that your question has now been answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since nobody is putting the solution into an answer, I will do so in order to wrap up this question.

Change your code from this:

```
myfunction1().then(myfunction2());
```

to this:

```
myfunction1().then(myfunction2);
```

You need to pass only a function reference to `.then()` so it can call the function LATER when the timing is appropriate.  When you put the parens after the function name, you were telling the JS interpreter to execute the function immediately and then pass the return result as the `.then()` handler.  That's why it wasn't executing in the desired order.

---

This is a very common mistake.  Just remember that putting parens after a function name causes it to be execute immediately.  Passing a function name by itself (without the parens) will just pass a function reference that can be called sometime later by the function/method you passed it to (which is what you want here).

Answer (score 0):

You must need to learn w.r.t promises chaining. You can simply do this.

```
myFunctionA().then(()=> 
   return myFunB;
).then(()=> {
   //Do stuff after function b execution.`k`
}
```

I haven't tested that but I hope it will work.
Please accept it as an answer if it works.